# How to differentiate between pan and scroll in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

is there a way to differentiate between pan and scroll in uiscrollview.
I use a `scrollGesture` to scroll between images with one finger on a `UIScrollView`. Problem is when I zoom into the image then `scrollGesture` fires.

I have tried two fingers for scrolling but this interferes with zoom gesture.
I have tried to disable `scrollGesture` when zoom is >1 but i still need to scroll while zoomed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this has been here for quite a long time and got no answer.
The correct answer is YOU CAN NOT.